# rewrite rule to simplify path with query string

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I think this can be accomplished with a rewrite rule in .htaccess file but I don't know regular expressions.  Basically what I want to do is make this path:
http://example.com/wp-content/themes/DiviFX/landing-local.php?phrase=abdominal-surgery
work as:
http://example.com/landing/abdominal-surgury or http://example.com/abdominal-surgury

Is this possible?  If so how?  Thanks.

I found this below rule using a mod-rewrite tool, it still isn't working though.  I put it in .htaccess file of public html directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /wp-content/themes/DiviFX/landing-local.php?phrase=$1 [L]
```

This is the top of the .htaccess file, it isn't doing anything for my rule:

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/$ /wp-content/themes/DiviFX/landing-local.php?phrase=$1 [L]
```

I also tried this and no luck either.  Any ideas?

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule landing-local/phrase/(.*)/ landing-local.php?phrase=$1
RewriteRule landing-local/phrase/(.*) landing-local.php?phrase=$1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (^|&)phrase=([^&]+)
RewriteRule .* /local/%2 [QSD,L]
```

You can remove `/local` if you don't want that in there.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, unfortunately I still can't get it to work.  I'm running out of ideas. It's hard to tell what is happening too because nothing is written to the wordpress debug log.

Comment: @JBD I have tested the above and it definitely redirects in the way you requested. `/wp-content/themes/DiviFX/landing-local.php?phrase=abdominal-surgery` goes to `/landing/abdominal-surgery`. Did you remember to turn RewriteEngine On? Do you have any other redirects in your .htaccess file? Did you set some sort of rewriting in the Wordpress settings under Permalinks? This could probably be achieved using the permalink settings anyway.

Comment: Hi, thanks.  Yeah, I don't know, I wasn't able to get anything to work with the url rewrites, I tried everything from writing it in wordpress to various .htaccess files and finally gave up and finished the task a different way (created a bunch of word press pages as landing pages and wrote a plugin to populate them).  Not the solution I wanted but it works, I still want to understand the url redirects, I must be missing something.  I'll try it on simple stuff with fresh word press installs in the future maybe to try and get it to work.